# Add command-line UI to existing asp.net MVC web app Visual Studio project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

Please let me know if this question has already been answered elsewhere. I wasn't able to find it, but I have a hard time believing it's not out there already.

I have an intranet web app project in Visual Studio 2012 written in C#, using asp.net and MVC. I'd like to add a command-line UI, so users have a choice whether to go through the browser or just hit the app directly from their shell. The web app merely allows a pretty way to upload a file/folder and display the output, so writing a command-line UI is trivial.

What's the best way to add a second UI to my existing project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that your main MVC project is divided into layers that separate the UI from the implementation code. This means that code that can be shared by the MVC application and by whatever project you use to publish the EndPoints for your command-line tool.

Then, create a new project that exposes the methods you want to access using the command-line tool. The easiest way to do this is using the newest Web API, which will be very easy to comprehend if you've used MVC controllers in the past.

Then, you need to create the command line tool.

- This project can be written in another solution since it will only be
  used to consume the API endpoints.
- You need to create a mini-parser so users can pass arguments to function calls. Some reference articles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63374/C-NET-Command-Line-Argument-Parser-Reloaded)
- You need to give feedback to the user when he/she calls yourprocess.exe -? or yourprocess.exe -help so they know which
  commands are available
- And most importantly, you need to find a way to authenticate calls to the server. You can either do basic authentication or make use of
  a SSL Certificate. Here are some additional resources:

  - [Web API Authentication best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222527/web-api-authentication-best-practice)
  - [RESTFul Authentication with WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800954/restful-authentication-with-webapi)
  - [User Authentication in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731683/user-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api)
  - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api